# how to prevent updating a field in CakePHP 3 beforesave()?

Tags: forms, cakephp-3.0, before-save

In my form, if an input field is not changed, I don't want to update that particular field in database. How can I achieve this in beforesave() ? I tried `$entity->unset($fieldName);` but that doesn't work.

UPDATE:
In my form, for one filed, I am saving encrypted data in database, and in beforeFind(), if this field is not null in database, this input is set to `"*** ***"`. My encryption code for this field is in beforeSave(). I want to update this field only if it is not `"*** ***"`.

Comment: If you're following standard Cake practices (i.e. get, patch and save the entity), then what you're asking for should be happening already. If it's not, please provide some code and SQL log to demonstrate your scenario.

Comment: How about removing that field from the posted data before patching the entity, e.g. in `beforeMarshal`?

Comment: @GregSchmidt I tried ```if ($data['fieldName'] === "*** ***") {
            unset($data['fieldName']);
        }``` in beforeMarshal(). But that field is still updating as *** *** in database.

Comment: The value passed to `beforeMarshal` is an ArrayObject, not an array. Use [offsetUnset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.offsetunset.php) to remove a value from it.

Comment: thanks @GregSchmidt I have changed my code to ```if ($data['fieldName'] === "*** ***") {
            $data->offsetUnset("fieldName");
            //var_dump($data);die();   
        }``` $data does not have 'fieldname'. But still this filed is updating as "*** ***"

Answer (score 0):

my code is working fine when `$entity->unset($fieldName);` changed to`unset($entity->$fieldName);`